# Building a website theme like facebook?

Tags: date, pagination, bootstrap-datepaginator

i want to build a website that have the pagination by date like in facebook on Wordpress CMS. How can i archive that ?
It means how can i change the main query of wordpress from post per page to post per moth / perday ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display post by $\_POST\[date\] in wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845456/display-post-by-postdate-in-wordpress)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While we love helping people with their technical issues here, there are some questions that need a lot more detail to be sufficiently answered.  Your question is unfortunately very vague, and doesn't describe what technologies you are using or any attempts you have made.  You will be more likely to receive helpful answers if you can take a bit more time to explain your specific project and your current attempts at a solution.  See [ask].

Comment: It's hard to say it similar, i think i want to build a pagination like the facebook, with infinite scroll and the main pagination of wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think if you want a wordpress theme , i've discovered this DW timeline pro theme. it has the [pagination by date](http://demo.designwall.com/dw-timeline-pro/) function.

Other wise i think you can using this code from : https://github.com/keesiemeijer/date-pagination
It'll make the main query of your post from post per page to day, month or year.

Comment: Thanks, i've see the theme and it's exactly what i'm looking for. Just using the Github file you have and i got my pagination paging by month now.